# Boxplot with additional lines for 10th and 90th percentile in R

Tags: r, function, group-by, boxplot, percentile

Unfortunately I am not very experienced in R, but I need to solve a problem, which appears quite difficult to me, but probably is quite easy if one knows how to work with boxplots in R. I would be really grateful if you could help me with this:

I need to add **additional horizontal lines or dots** in a grouped boxplot diagram **for the 10th and 90th percentiles**. Besides this, the boxplot should entail the common features such as min, max, the box with the usual 25th percentile, median and 75th percentile and outliers.

I tried to adapt several of the solutions posted here, but none of them works for my case. One promising attempt would be similar to the solution below with writing a function -  but I need the median not the mean and besides this I would need to display the 10th and 90th percentile additionally not instead. Also, it is important to group the boxes by the variable *Col* (see sample code below):

If you could give me some ideas how to solve this, I would be really grateful!

```
dataset_stack <- structure(list(Col = c("Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", 
                       "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", 
                       "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", 
                       "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", 
                       "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", 
                       "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Red"), TTC = c(0.9, 
                                                                                 0.7, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.8, 0.1, 0, 0.7, 0.2, 0.7, 0.2, 
                                                                                 0, 0.8, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.3, 0.9, 0.8, 0.3, 1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 
                                                                                 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.9, 0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0, 
                                                                                 0.7, 0.4, 0.7)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                          -43L))

bp.vals <- function(x, probs=c(0.1, 0.25, 0.75, .9)) {
    r <- quantile(x, probs=probs , na.rm=TRUE)
    r = c(r[1:2], exp(mean(log(x))), r[3:4])
    names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
    r
  }

  # Sample usage of the function with the built-in mtcars data frame
  ggplot(dataset_stack, aes(x=factor(Col), y=TTC)) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=bp.vals, geom="boxplot")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `stat_summary()` function and adding a `fun()` to indicate specific `quantile()` and `median` as colored points. If your data contains outliers they would be shown for example in orange color:

```
ggplot(dataset_stack, aes(x=factor(Col), y=TTC)) +
     geom_boxplot(outlier.color = "orange3", outlier.size = 4) + 
     stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="darkred") +
     stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = \(x) quantile(x, 0.1,na.rm=T),shape=16, size=4,color="red")+
     stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = \(x) quantile(x, 0.9,na.rm=T),shape=16, size=4,color="blue")+
     theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want to show only e.g, `mean` in black, `median` in dark red, `min`, and `max` values with e.g `grey` color you could use the function `stat_summary()` :

```
ggplot(dataset_stack, aes(x=factor(Col), y=TTC)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = "orange3", outlier.size = 4) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="black") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="darkred") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="min", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="grey") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="max", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="grey") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

adding all together:

```
ggplot(dataset_stack, aes(x=factor(Col), y=TTC)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.color = "orange3", outlier.size = 4) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="black") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="darkred") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="min", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="grey") +
  stat_summary(fun.y="max", geom="point", shape=16, size=4, color="grey") +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = \(x) quantile(x, 0.1,na.rm=T),shape=16, size=4,color="red")+
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = \(x) quantile(x, 0.9,na.rm=T),shape=16, size=4,color="blue")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so very much! This is really great! It works perfectly with the original data and shows exactly what I want to display! Really thanks!